How to Store and Retrieve User ID in Next.js?
I'm working on a Next.js project and I need to store the userId after a user logs in. This userId is essential for fetching user-specific data and generating dynamic URLs for the user profile menu.
Here’s the workflow I’m trying to implement:

User logs in.
Store the userId securely.
Use the stored userId to fetch user-specific data.
Generate dynamic profile URLs like /profile/{userId}.

What is the best practice to securely store the userId and retrieve it for generating the dynamic profile URLs? Should I use cookies, local storage, or another method? How can I ensure that this approach is both secure and efficient?
Here’s a snippet of my login function:
const handleLogin = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('/api/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
  });
  const data = await response.json();

  if (data.success) {
    // How to securely store data.userId for later use?
  }
};

In the best case, I can use either userId on the client side and also on the server side
Edit:
Trying to use cookies failed with "Failed to compile":
You're importing a component that needs next/headers. That only works in a Server Component which is not supported in the pages/ directory

My MENU const is stored under /src/configs/menu.tsx

You should store it with the session on the server, because you cannot trust the client to tell you the correct id.

The best practice for storing and getting userId on both client and server side is to store it in cookies. Cookie is faster and more secured compared to localstorage. Although cookie has some limitations like you cannot mutate cookie on the server side but you can read them on the server side. To set or delete a cookie, you need to use a client component. Another limitation that I noticed was you cannot store large objects in cookie as it has a limitation of 4096 bytes but I think that will be more than enough to store userId and other session informations.
I'm suggesting you a package which is best for handling cookies in nextjs named cookies-next.
assuming that the function is called from a client component:
 const handleLogin = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('/api/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
  });
  const data = await response.json();

  if (data.success) {
    // How to securely store data.userId for later use?
    setCookie('userId', data.userId, { maxAge: 60 * 6 * 24 });
  }
};

I'd be more than happy to hear from you if you need more assistance. Thank you

Thank you for your reply. I will try it out. Why would you choose a third party libary when Next.Js has also its own cookie function?
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies

Well, I chose it because it's simpler than the built in one..

I see! So, you're trying to set the cookie on server side which is impossible in nextjs 13 or further. All you need to do is, create a server action function and then make your component as a client component and then you'll be able to mutate the cookie after the server action function invoked.

I turned the component to a client component and created a new server side file under /src/lib/session.tsx to retrieve the cookie. Now I am getting an error like: Error: Server Functions cannot be called during initial render. This would create a fetch waterfall. Try to use a Server Component to pass data to Client Components instead.

Ok, I've got it. The problem was in my stack. I called a server component, then a client component, another client component and then a server component. I had to rethink the arrangement of the menus and now it seems to work. Thank you very much for your support

Pleasure is always mine. It'd be more than appreciating if you've accepted my response as the answer then..

You can encrypt your session and set cookies on server side
Here is a good example in nextjs docs for doing the same
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/authentication#2-encrypting-and-decrypting-sessions
